# Testing promise request in nodejs using mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, mocha.js

I want to test the response in nodejs using request, I tried doing some unit test but I cannot get inside the request function

```
let request = require('request');

function doRequest() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if(!err) {
                // Test error
            } else {
                // Test success
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: `request` is deprecated use `nock` for http server mocking

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use nock instead of request, but since you need to use request module here is an example

```
const request = require('request');

const requestCB = (resolve, reject) => async (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error) {
        // Test success
        console.log(response);
        resolve();
    } else {
        // Test error
        console.error(error);
        // reject();
    }
};

function doRequest(options) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, requestCB(resolve, reject));
    })
        .then(() => {})
        .catch((err) => {});
}

const options = {
    /* you can use this url if you want to test
     * https://api.github.com/repos/request/request
     */
    url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request',
    },
};

// call doRequest
doRequest(options);
```